# How to add x-axis on Sankey Chart (Recharts)?

Tags: charts, sankey-diagram, recharts

Is there any way to add x-axis in a Sankey Chart using Recharts?

Here is a sample code for Sankey,

```
function SankeyDemo() {
return (
<div className="sankey-charts">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span style={{fontSize: '16px', fontFamily: 'Open Sans'}} >SANKEY CHART</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="lastModified" style={{fontSize: '12px', fontFamily: 'Open Sans'}} >Last data refresh: {dataSankey.dataRefreshed}</span>
    </div>
    <Sankey width={450} height={300} data={dataSankey}
    link={<SankeyLink />}
    node={<SankeyNode containerWidth={960} />}  
    >
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id={'linkGradient'}>
          <stop offset="0%" stopColor="#d9d9db" />
          <stop offset="100%" stopColor="#d9d9db" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <Tooltip />
    </Sankey>

  </div>
</div>
```

Also, here is a sample output of what I need,

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: recharts provide sankey chart implementation ?